# Too many requests to api needed in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, axios, get

I need to send about 4000 requests to an api, to get information for every user and save it in my database. Is there a way I can do this, without connection error? Because while testing, it makes my internet connection struggle.

Comment: You didn't post what connection error you're getting. I would do it in batches, say 500 requests every 5 minutes or whatever your connection can handle at one time. You can also space out every request to take 2 seconds per request in a long running task so it doesn't overwhelm your connection. I suppose it doesn't matter how long it takes as long as it gets done, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it does not matter, if it takes up to 30mins. I would then try this batches. Start with 100 requests maybe, and get a feeling for how many request I can make per minute. Since I am new to nodejs. What would be a good way to pause it for 1 minute e.g.? The requests are within a promise

Comment: While not the only approachs, I would start with `setTimeout` first, if that's not suitable then a task scheduler like a cron job.